Measuring FPS with high-resolution timer giving strange results?
My fps jumps around from 250 to 5000 with a very very simple program. Is this normal? What is causing this to happen?
// ...store variables
// .. get frequency (it is 10,000,000)

// .. start loop
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartCounts);
    
    // very small task adding and subtracting numbers
    
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndCounts);
    
    Output.FPS.QuadPart = Frequency.QuadPart / (EndCounts.QuadPart - StartCounts.QuadPart);
// .. end of loop

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps

What is "very small task", does it produce any actual side effects? Did you enable compiler optimizations?

In two words: preemptive multitasking.
